Что такое репутация и как её заработать?
Задавались ли вы вопросом: "У меня недостаточно репутации для определённых действий, что мне делать?"
Если да, то тогда эта статья для вас!
В этой статье вы узнаете:

Для чего нужна репутация
Сколько репутации нужно для определённых действий
Какие способы заработка репутации есть на сайте


Итак, начнём наш тур!
1. Для чего нужна репутация
Для начала поговорим о том, что такое репутация. Приведу цитату из статьи "Что такое репутация? Как можно её заработать (и потерять)?":

Репутация — это упрощённая мера того, насколько вам доверяет сообщество; чтобы её заработать, требуется убедить других участников в правильности и достоверности изложенной вами информации. Основные действия на сайте, включая создание вопросов, ответов и предложение правок, не зависят от репутации. Но чем выше репутация, тем больше у вас привилегий.

Иными словами репутация нужна для совершения вами определённых действий на сайте. Чем больше у вас репутация, тем больше вам даётся привилегий, предоставляющих для вас возможности сайта.
2. Сколько репутации нужно для определённых действий
Основными привилегиями являются:

Голосовать за — 15 баллов репутации;
Отмечать тревогой — 15 баллов репутации;
Комментирование вопросов/ответов — 50 баллов репутации;
Голосовать против — 125 баллов репутации;
Правка вопросов и ответов без утверждения — 2 000 баллов репутации;
Закрывать и переоткрывать вопросы — 3 000 баллов репутации.

Подробнее про привилегии вы можете прочитать здесь.
3. Какие способы заработка репутации есть на сайте
На самом деле их немного:

Задавать хорошие вопросы и предоставлять качественные ответы.

Это является эффективным способом получения репутации. Вы получаете + 10 баллов к своей репутации за каждый голос "за" по вашему вопросу/ответу от других пользователей.
Если ваш ответ принимает автор вопроса, вы получаете за принятие + 15 баллов репутации.
Пожалуйста, помните о том, что нужно публиковать качественные и подробные вопросы/ответы для того, чтобы не только дождаться ответа на свой вопрос (если вы задаёте вопрос) или ответить на вопрос автора (если отвечаете), но и для того, чтобы другие люди могли воспользоваться вашим вопросом/ответом, если он является полезным. Помните о том, что Stack Overflow это в первую очередь база знаний!
По вопросам/ответам, не являющимися полезными, могут проголосовать "против" — за каждый такой голос у вас отнимут 2 балла репутации. Если против вашего вопроса/ответа проголосовали единожды — переживать не стоит, это нормально.
Однако если вы видите последовательное голосование "против" вашего конкретного вопроса/ответа, то стоит задуматься о том, что он может быть низкого качества. Тогда вам следует его улучшить путём редактирования или удалить его.

Также вы можете "попытать удачу" приняв участие в конкурсе! О том, что это такое, вы можете узнать здесь. Победа в конкурсе может принести вам от 50 до 500 баллов репутации! Внимательно прочитайте условие начатого конкурса, чтобы лучшим образом оформить ваш ответ.


Исправлять вопросы/ответы других пользователей.

Не очень эффективный, но довольно простой способ заработка репутации. За каждую вашу утверждённую правку вы получаете + 2 балла к своей репутации.
Помните о том, что к редакции вопросов/ответов пользователей есть определённые правила, которых нужно придерживаться. За некачественные правки у вас могут отнять репутацию (- 2 балла за каждую правку, которую откатывают), а также если вы будете предлагать множество некачественных правок, то вам могут ограничить доступ к возможностям править вопросы/ответы.
Вы можете предложить на проверку максимум 5 правок — вы не сможете предложить ещё одну правку до тех пор, пока не примут одну из ваших предложенных.
Подробнее о том, что и как следует редактировать в вопросах/ответах, описано в статье "Как стать хорошим начинающим редактором?"

Пожалуй это всё, что касается того, как заработать репутацию. Пожалуйста, соблюдайте правила сайта: не пытайтесь совершать определённые действия, если вам не хватает для них репутации (к этому относится оставление ответа, являющегося комментарием) — за недобросовестные действия и нарушения правил сайта к вам могут быть применены санкции!
Хороших вам вопросов/ответов/правок и увидимся на Stack Overflow на русском!

Странно, что нет ссылки на эту страницу в ответе https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges

@aepot, "Подробнее про привилегии вы можете прочитать здесь."

Не заметил, да.
